# How to get a calendar-style DatePicker in Android?

Tags: android, datepicker, calendar, picker

I want to add a calendar-style date picker in Android, where the user will be able to select a date from a display that shows a calendar for one month.

I googled many topics, but haven't found a solution, so I'm trying to create one myself. I tried getting the dates and displaying them like a calendar, but I wasn't successful.

Comment: By "pattern", do you really mean displayed like a calendar?

Comment: yes.. but only one month

Comment: I edited your question to clarify that you're looking for something like a calendar. Could you edit it also, with the [edit link](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/30851815/edit) below it, to explain more about what you tried and what happened when you tried it?